# Chrome appending -- to end of filename

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome

```
string fileName = "test.txt";
byte[] docBytes = getDocumentBytes();

return File(docBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
```

This returns a file called "test.txt" on Firefox and Edge, however on Chrome it returns a file called "test.txt--".
Does anyone know why it behaves in this manner? Is there a way to fix this in the code?

Answer (score 2):

Well this was hard to find out.

Chrome converts whitespace at the end of the filename into '-'.

```
 return File(docBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName.Trim());
```

The trim fixes this problem.